# How call and compile function from elf to my binary?

Tags: c, gcc, elf, disassembly

I have a binary file (ELF) that I don't write, but I want to use 1 function from this binary (I know the address/offset of the function), that function not exported from the binary.

My goal is to call this function from my C code that I write and compile this function statically in my binary (I compile with gcc).

How can I do that please?

Comment: Is the code this ELF file contains position-independent? What is the output of the `file` command on this binary?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer the

> call to this function from my c code that I write

part.

The below works under certain assumptions, like dynamic linking and position independent code.  I haven't thought for too long about what happens if they are broken (let's experiment/discuss, if there's interest).

```
$ cat lib.c
int data = 42;
static int foo () { return data; }
```

`gcc -fpic -shared lib.c -o lib.so`

```
$ nm lib.so  | grep foo
00000000000010e9 t foo
```

The above reproduces having the address that you know. The address we know now is `0x10e9`. It is the virtual address of `foo` before relocation. We'll model the relocation the dynamic loader does by hand by simply adding the base address at which `lib.so` gets loaded.

```
$ cat 1.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <elf.h>

#define FOO_VADDR 0x10e9

typedef int(*func_t)();

int callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    if (!(strstr(info->dlpi_name, "lib.so")))
        return 0;
    Elf64_Addr addr = info->dlpi_addr + FOO_VADDR;
    func_t f = (func_t)addr;
    int res = f();
    printf("res = %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    void *handle = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        puts("failed to load");
        return 1;
    }
    dl_iterate_phdr(&callback, NULL);
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

And now...

```
$ gcc 1.c -ldl  && ./a.out
res = 42
```

Voila -- it worked! That was fun.

Credit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390514/2104472) was helpful.

If you have questions, feel free to read the man and ask in the comments.

As for

> compile this function statically in my binary

I don't know off the bat. This would be trickier. Why do you want that? Also, do you know whether the function depends on some data (or maybe it calls other functions) in the original ELF file, like in the example above?

Comment: but `1.c` use `lib.c` as dinamic. I want compile the function statically

Comment: Well, that's a hard task in the general case, in particular because the function can reference data via `rip`-relative addressing, and call other functions, etc -- so you'll need to extract all dependencies. I think you need to disassemble the thing, replace all relative and absolute jumps and references with symbolic values and then assemble and link as usual.

Comment: if the function was exported in `lib.c` is tgat was easy to call? and when I compiled it ,it was statically?

Comment: @Keystone it would be somewhat _easier_, but not _easy_. There's more information on exported symbols in libraries: address, size, and relocations would be helpful. Still, you'll face the same fundamental problem: you need to extract already compiled code and recompile (reassemble, actually) without the rest of the library. And that is hard, because the toolchain is not meant for that.

Comment: in your example you show how to call function from binary that you complied as ` -shared`.  Is there any way to call to function in binary that I know the offset ,but this binary didn't compile as shared??

Comment: Is it a position independent execucable? What is the output of the `file` command?